When the initial page load time is shown in Clarity recordings, can Clarity detect issues with the internet speed of that particular user?
"The page took approximately 16.6 seconds to load, which is more than half of the total session duration and could indicate performance issues that may affect user experience." Does Clarity analyze the internet speed of that particular user
I was analyzing a video recording and while looking at the particular insights the statement is provided by it

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
